# How to pass build.grade properties from IntelliJ

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, gradle, gradlew

I have in my build.gradle:

```
if( project.hasProperty('jboss') ) //...
```

and I know I can pass this property from command line

```
./gradlew test -Pjboss
```

and it works perfectly. But there is also in IntelliJ Run/Debug configuration screen. And I consider how pass there such params.

[image]

Comment: Did you try in script parameters?

Comment: Yes I have tried in VM options to pass -Pjboss and in Script parameters and I'm getting error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: in VM options A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
It's odd but It now seems to work correctly!
Previously I have something like class/ or app not found

Comment: I consider now Why when I'm starting Integration Tests in JUnit using IntelliJ Run/Debug Gradle configuration than they starts Wildly (embedded server) and when using ./gradlew They don't start this server and I must to run it manually?

Comment: @MichałZiobro it seems that in IntelliJ you can configure `Command Line Arguments` under `Run options`. It seems that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Or as far I as see you can use `Script parameters`.